# How to disable Function keys on Linux (software or hardware)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard

I am setting up a **kiosk** mode computer in fairly low traffic setting (3 to 5 people per hour). The system will be Ubuntu and it will run a browser to present a questionnaire (via limesurvey) on the local machine (localhost) to people who happen to be in the reception / waiting area. The computer will not be network connected. People will have physical access to screen, keyboard and mouse only.

**I would like to disable the function keys and right click on the mouse**. I searched internet and found very little on how to disable keys physically - if I tried that, I think, it would be time consuming and prone to breaking, so maintaining it would be hard.

Would it be possible to use a startup script that would disable keys via xmodmap, or something else? I have not used xmodmap apart from a few quick instances of occasional troubleshooting, so I know very little about it.

Comment: Yes, you can use `xmodmap` to delete the mappings for the function keys. You can also map the mouse buttons to other mouse buttons, e.g. the right click to button 10, say (in the hope that your applications don't react to this button).

Answer (score 0):

I got my perfect setup. It is described fully in another post, but the essence is - use **i3** tiling window manager, configure some key restrictions in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and you are good to go. Only those keybindings that you want will work. Just comment out the unneeded ones from `~/.config/i3/conf` The post is: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344374/how-to-configure-kiosk-with-wayland-xorg